# In Geocoder here-api what are the different types of View

Tags: here-api

I am moving from Google to Here-api Geocoding service.In the Response JSON object there is a property View which is an array. I was not able to find in the documentation what types of objects might be in this collection. It seems that there is a type-_type property for every View and from all my testing I got only one object inside this array and it is always from the same type  "_type": "SearchResultsViewType". My questions are:
Is it possible this collection that View collection to contain more than one object? Are they from the same "_type" or from a different "_type"?In short, besides probably ViewId how are different Views objects separated?

I made numerous requests to Geogoder API with switching on and off different parameters. I have searched here and in the API documentation.

This is how the Response object is looking now

```
  {
"Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
        "Timestamp": "2019-04-18T11:48:31.306+0000"
    },
    "View": [
        {    "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
            "ViewId": 0,
            "Result": .....
```

Comment: Which geocode api are you using? If possible please give your code.

Comment: Are you looking for search response? https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html

Comment: Yes, I am looking for Geocoder API Search response, "View" element in particular